How can i retrieve a list of posts from my wordpress-rest api, with the sticke posts on top?
When I want to get the posts from my Wordpress Rest API, the sticky posts are not at the top, but are sorted by date like the others.
When I try to sort by sticky
wp-json/wp/v2/posts?orderby=sticky

I get this error message:
code: "rest_invalid_param",
message: "Invalid parameter(s): orderby",

If I append the following parameters instead
wp-json/wp/v2/posts?ignore_sticky_posts=0

or
wp-json/wp/v2/posts?ignore_sticky_posts=1

the sorting does not change.
How can I make the sticky posts always be at the top?

you can retrieve sticky posts with the endpoint wp/v2/posts/?sticky=true.

Thanks, but I already know that. But I need the full list, with the sticky posts on top. Do I really have to get the sticky post and the non-sticky posts separately and then combine, and not simply by ordering all posts so that the sticky ones are on top?

if you don't want to combine that on client side with the answer of Webpress, you can create a new endpoint on the api : https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

In the WordPress REST API, there's no built-in parameter to sort posts by sticky status directly. However, you can achieve your goal by fetching the sticky posts and non-sticky posts separately and then combining them in your application.
Fetch Sticky Posts: Use the endpoint to get only sticky posts:
wp-json/wp/v2/posts?sticky=true

Fetch Non-Sticky Posts: Use the endpoint to get non-sticky posts:
wp-json/wp/v2/posts?ignore_sticky_posts=1

Combine Results: After retrieving both sets of posts, combine the sticky posts with the non-sticky ones in your application logic.
async function fetchPosts() {
const stickyPostsResponse = await fetch('wp-json/wp/v2/posts?sticky=true');
const stickyPosts = await stickyPostsResponse.json();

const nonStickyPostsResponse = await fetch('wp-json/wp/v2/posts?ignore_sticky_posts=1');
const nonStickyPosts = await nonStickyPostsResponse.json();

const allPosts = [...stickyPosts, ...nonStickyPosts];
return allPosts;

}
